# When I click the element it doesn't prevent the default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have the following code:

HTML:

[image: href code]

JavaScript:

```js
$('.tombol-acc').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = $(this).attr('href');

  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      document.location.href = href;
    }
  })
});
```

but when I click the element, it doesn't prevent the default action. Why?

Comment: Maybe the code is running before the elements are loaded on the page? Maybe you didn't include the jQuery library? Maybe there's some code before this that's throwing a runtime error? Maybe the script has a syntax error? Maybe the HTML is invalid? Maybe the element doesn't have a default action? Don't know. There's not enough info in the question.

Comment: Please, post the exact `<a>` html.

Comment: Your html code has problem, send it in good format or take a screen shot and send it again.

Comment: yes, the sweet alert is not working before the href code is running

Comment: Please, post the generated `<a>` HTML

Comment: It has to be something up with how your href is rendering.  I just did a test with your code but with the href filled out with a normal address and the code worked fine.  So view the source of your page to see how the href is being rendered and maybe that will show you why you're having this issue.